# Cannot read USB device

Tags: usb, lsusb

I am trying to read a USB device (a robot arm), which works well on Machine A, but does not work on Machine B. Machine A is a desktop, Machine B is a laptop, both are running Ubuntu 14.04, and both have a USB 2.0 port.

It turns out that Machine B cannot even see the USB device when running `lsusb`, whereas Machine A prints out a line detailing the USB device as expected. However, all other USB devices I've tried are recognized by both machines.

So my question is: What may be the cause of why Machine B cannot recognize this particular device, and how may I go about solving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, plug the machine to the device A (where it works), open a terminal and type:

`gksudo nautilus`

Nautilus file browser will open, right click on your USB under `"Devices"` then go to the `"Permissions"` tab.

You have 3 groups, Me, Group and Others. Set them all with `"Create and delete files"` permissions and try to plug the USB to the B machine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Actually, the device does not appear under `"Devices"`, I only have the hard drive listed there. But the device does appear under `"lsusb"`...

Comment: Btw. what is that "device" if we might know? Not an USB Stick apparently :)

Comment: It is a robotic arm -- the Kinova Mico :)

Comment: Are both machines up to date? (apt-get update /upgrade /dist-upgrade) Maybe USB2.0/USB3.0 power input? My clue would be that some kind of update/package on machine A allows is to see the hardware and that is missing on machine B. Both are running 14.04 you say. I would try to compare added PPA's and installed packages via the Synaptic Package Manager. Looking somewhere else doesn't make any sense. If somebody else would have a hint, he would post it already imo.